# Opening port so that pgAdmin on Windows 7 can connect to PostgreSQL on Debian on VirtualBox

Tags: postgresql, windows-7, port, virtualbox, pgadmin

Hello all :) I'm a having a little trouble connecting this.

On Windows 7 about my Debian 6 on VitualBox configured with Host-only Adapter:

```
>nmap -T4 -A -v 192.168.56.1
[...]
5432/tcp  unknown postgresql
```

On the Debian, PostgreSQl is listening:

```
>netstat -tulpn

tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:5432  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2432/postgres
tcp6 0  0  :::5432       :::*       LISTEN  2432/postgres
```

.. and the port is opened

```
>iptables -nL

ACCEPT tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0./0  tcp  dpt:5432
```

.. and Postgres is accepting all the connections in postgresql.conf

```
listen-addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

In Windows I have this error message from pdAdmin:

```
Server doesn't listen

The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) 
Is the server running on host "192.168.56.1" and accepting TCP/IP 
connections on port 5432? 

If you encounter this message, please check if the server you're trying 
to contact is actually running PostgreSQL on the given port. 
Test if you have network connectivity from your client to the server 
host using ping or equivalent tools. Is your network / VPN / SSH tunnel /
 firewall configured correctly? 

For security reasons, PostgreSQL does not listen on all available 
IP addresses on the server machine initially. In order to access 
the server over the network, you need to enable listening on the 
address first. 

For PostgreSQL servers starting with version 8.0, this is controlled 
using the "listen_addresses" parameter in the postgresql.conf file. 
Here, you can enter a list of IP addresses the server should listen 
on, or simply use '*' to listen on all available IP addresses. For 
earlier servers (Version 7.3 or 7.4), you'll need to set the 
"tcpip_socket" parameter to 'true'. 

You can use the postgresql.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III 
to edit the postgresql.conf configuration file. After changing this 
file, you need to restart the server process to make the setting effective. 

If you double-checked your configuration but still get this error 
message, it's still unlikely that you encounter a fatal PostgreSQL 
misbehaviour. You probably have some low level network connectivity 
problems (e.g. firewall configuration). Please check this thoroughly 
before reporting a bug to the PostgreSQL community.
```

Best regards

Comment: Can you show the result of `ifconfig` on the guest OS?

Answer (score 1):

What about your `pg_hba.conf` file? 
Have you configured it to accept connections from hosts in the 192.168.56.0 network?
Try to add this line and restart Postgres:

```
# VitualBox Host-Only Adapter
host      all     all     192.168.56.0/24     md5
```

If it's a testing environment you could even replace `192.168.56.0/24` with `0.0.0.0/0` and forget about it.

Comment: _Connection refused_ is never caused by `pg_hba.conf`, because the connection attempt doesn't even reach the postgres server.